# Role Title Word That Conveys a Sense of Direction/Command as well as Engagement of Particular Skills in Work

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, ambiguity, minimal-pairs

I'm looking for an eloquent word, if one exists, for a role in one's profession whereby they direct and mentor a team with a particular set of skills, but also clearly *engage* in work with said skills themselves. My concern is that one might think a "Director" may not necessarily engage in the work themselves, but rather oversee it without getting their hands into it, per se.

For example, a "Design and Development Director" may not actually sit down and do design or development work, but rather oversee a team of designers and developers who actually do the work. That's how I've always thought of that type of role, at least.

I know roles that include "Lead" or "Senior" in the title are common, but I don't feel like those terms convey a true sense of the level of leadership and directional command that the term "Director" does.

Am I asking for a rare word, or even a word that doesn't exist? Or is there a common word that conveys both a sense of command as well as a sense of engagement, simultaneously? Alternately, if there's an eloquent word pairing that fits this quest, I'm open to exploring that as well.

Comment: You're going to hate this but: the standard phrasing on (American) resumes is ***player/coach***. Try searching for that term on LinkedIn, if you can stomach it.

Comment: You're right. I'm not a fan. I also prefer "mentor" to "coach" but I feel like "mentor" is starting to gain 'buzzword' status, which is a bit disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

I use "Lead" in my profession... but, I see your point - it doesn't pack much of a wallop. How about "Design and Development ***Facilitator***" ?

Comment: Facilitator is decent. I think it does convey both words, with the exception of the part of the definition where it states "the facilitator takes a neutral position". But that's one definition among many. In the design industry, I think most people know it to mean both leadership and participation/engagement.

Answer (score 0):

One term that has been used is

***working manager***

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Working+manager&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CWorking%20manager%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bworking%20manager%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWorking%20Manager%3B%2Cc0

shows that this hit its peak usage in the 1980s.  I don't know what might have supplanted it.  It does occur in some job postings.

Comment: Hmmm. It does indeed sound like something from the mid 20th century.